# Is there something like "minimum" as opposed to "limit" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, limit

"limit" is ensuring that there is a maximum number of rows in the result set.

I would be looking for the functional opposite of that : something like "minimum" which would ensure that the query produced at least the minimum number of rows otherwise it would return an empty set.

If there something like that ?

Comment: The short answer is no, but there are various ways to accomplish that. Are you looking for ways to do that?

Comment: Yes, I would be interested. I'm looking for a way to do it in the query to avoid changing the code in many places...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a simple way to do exactly what you are looking to do in a query.  `LIMIT` can be used with two terms in the `LIMIT offset, row_count` format, which would return an empty set if the query failed to produce `offset` rows, but it would not return those first rows in any case.

The only way I've been able to modify a query to accomplish what you are looking for is by repeating the entire select query as a subquery, like this example:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 
  WHERE [where_conditions] 
  AND 20 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE [where_conditions])
```

This is unlikely to be a very efficient query, and it will result in some strange looking queries, but it may accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I came to the same conclusion so far so I'll accept the answer.